# What is the first fantasy work to feature both dwarves and dwarfs?

Tags: history-of, dwarves

A staple trope in fantasy and indeed European folklore is a race of short humans, usually fond of mining; these mythical creatures are usually spelt dwarves after Tolkien. They do not exist in real life.

A smaller number of fantasy works, most notably A Song of Ice and Fire, feature ‘dwarfs’, that is to say human beings who through a genetic condition are of short stature. Obviously, there are many people with dwarfism in the real world!

What is the first work of fantasy to feature both a mythical race of dwarves and a human being with dwarfism?

Comment: Certainly not the first, but Harry Potter has both 'midgets' and dwarfs

Comment: Depending on how you stretch genetic condition, the Lord of the Rings itself could qualify. Hobbits are an offshoot of men, whereas Dwarves are quite different.

Comment: @Nolimon I think they would at most be [pygmies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmy_peoples), not dwarfs (although maybe you could argue that they're a different subspecies instead). So, OP, do pygmies count?

Comment: In a foreword to *The Hobbit* (1937) Tolkien mentioned that he used "dwarves" to distinguish from "dwarfs" (midgets), so technically, he had both in a book back then, if only in a foreword.

Comment: In *Knights of the Dinner Table*, Brian played a dwarf mage character called Black Lotus (aka "Teflon Billy"). Character information (I forget which issue this was in) revealed that his claims to be related to various notable Dwarven families were dubious at best, and I've always wondered since then if he was a human with dwarfism who was pretending to be the other kind of dwarf.

Comment: ehhhh, Tolkin had a fable for spelling stuff different: Elb / Elf - Dwarv / Dwarf - Nazghul / Lich

Comment: @clockw0rk huh? He doesn't use Elb, and Elf was already the normal spelling (with slightly idiosyncratic capitalisation). He also uses Dwarf in the singular, only using Dwarves in the plural, and whilst Nazgul have some similarities with Liches as conceived of today, that conception mostly dates to after him and he might be expected to object to such a term on philological grounds (coming from Old English lic literally meaning "body")

Comment: In _The Death Gate Cycle_, we eventually learn that all four fantasy races are offshoots of humans, so does it count if dwarfs and dwarves are the same thing? (That said I don't recall any human dwarfs featured in the series)

Comment: @Valorum Midgets? I don't remember that and a check of the HP wiki didn't turn anything up. Although it did say Flitwick is short because he is part goblin, is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - Repeatedly referred to in the text (by Ron) "*‘Oh yeah,’ said Ron, who had obviously forgotten. ‘Hey – hey, you lot! Midgets!’* and "*‘Aaaaah,’ said Ron, imitating Professor Trelawney’s mystical whisper, ‘when two Neptunes appear in the sky, it is a sure sign that a midget in glasses is being born, Harry …’*

Comment: @Valorum Ah gotcha, I don't have a searchable HP copy handy.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - HP is, of course, set in a world that approximates our own, except with added wizardry. Any urban fantasy with dwarves is basically going to have dwarfs, even if they're not explicitly mentioned

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I don't recall it canon that Flitwick was part goblin, or even a little person.  The books described him as being short in stature, but not abnormally so.  It was the movies casting Warwick Davis in the role that made him an actual little person, a casting decision of which Rowling said: "*I must admit, I was taken aback when I saw the film Flitwick, who looks very much like a goblin/elf (I’ve never actually asked the film-makers precisely what he is), because the Flitwick in my imagination simply looks like a very small old man.*"  Neither books nor films say he's part goblin.

Answer (score 26):

The [Discworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld) series of novels by Terry Pratchett.

They have Dwarves, which are a separate species to humans.

They also have a recurring character [Nobby](https://wiki.lspace.org/Nobby_Nobbs) [Nobbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankh-Morpork_City_Watch#Corporal_Nobby_Nobbs), a human of well below average height. He is described as being shorter than most dwarves. He carries a certificate to prove that he is human.

First appearance, [Guards! Guards!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guards!_Guards!) 1989.

Comment: *I, after hearing evidence from a number of experts, including Mrs Slipdry the midwife,
certify that **the balance of probability** is that the bearer of this document, C. W. St John Nobbs, is a human being.*

Comment: may be worth noting that illustrations on book covers don't appear to show him as having proportionally short limbs (he is especially identifiable on the cover of Night Watch where he is shown as a child with his finger tips at about the level of the top of his oversized boots, likely around his knees, making them proportionally _longer_ than is typical for humans). Given Pratchett's tendency to address aspects of his earlier work that later struck him as having problematic implications, I think the lack of such comment about dwarfs likely indicates that he did not think of Nobbs as one

Comment: @Tristan Might help to specify/link which book cover(s).  There's apparently been quite a few of them.  My copy doesn't show the character at all, it's just a dragon on a flat green background.

Comment: a dragon on a green background on the cover of Night Watch? 0.o I mean the Paul Kidby cover illustration based on Rembrandt's The Night Watch which apparently is on the British Edition

Comment: the Josh Kirby covers on the earlier watch novels often make it hard to reliably identify specific characters due to their busy-ness, but I've never noticed a (certifiably) human character with dwarfish traits

Comment: @Tristan Oh, sorry, that was *Guards! Guards!*.  *Night Watch* just has a badge and some brass knuckles on a black background.

Comment: Josh Kirby's art was beautiful in its way, but  he quite often misunderstood the description. Pratchett described Twoflower as having a second pair of eyes, i.e. he wore spectacles which were unknown to Rincewind.  But Kirky drew him with four literal eyes.  Here is a cover by a different artist, Graham Higgins.  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f8s4nAO5L.jpg